# Why is my jQuery inline code is blocking jQuery code in MVC3 DateTime Editor Template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datetimepicker

I have a DateTime.cshtml template in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates which uses the [TimePicker Addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to implement a jQuery DateTime picker. This had been working fine until.....

I recently added some inline jQuery to my CheckOut page to handle removing items from a shopping cart and this has caused the jQuery DateTime picker to no longer appear when editing date/times.  The MVC date formatting part of the template (see below) is still being applied, but something about the inline jQuery is not playing nice with the template jQuery.

If I comment out the inline jQuery on my CheckOut View, the DateTime picker appears as it should when I click to edit a date/time field.

Can anyone see which part of my inline jQuery is clashing with the template jQuery?

**DateTime.cshtml Template**

```
    @model Nullable<System.DateTime> 

@if ( Model.HasValue ) { 
   @Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm tt}" , Model.Value ) , new { @class = "textbox" , @style = "width:200px;" } ) 
} 
else { 
   @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm tt}", DateTime.Now), new { @class = "textbox", @style = "width:200px;" }) 
} 

@{ 
string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix; 
string id = name.Replace( ".", "_" ); 
} 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@id").datetimepicker
            ({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                showStatus: true,
                showWeeks: true,
                highlightWeek: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                showAnim: "scale",
                ampm: true,
                hour: 12,
                minute: 0,
                stepMinute: 5,
                hourMin: 6,
                hourMax: 16,
                showOptions: {
                    origin: ["top", "left"]
                }
            });
    }); 
</script>
```

**CheckOut View jQuery**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteID).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteID).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }
                        //Hide the 'Checkout' button if there is no items in the cart.
                        if (data.CartTotal == 0) {
                            $('#checkout-button').fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Relevant generated HTML**

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Order_PickUpDateTime">Pick up Date and Time</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

<input class="textbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="Pick up date and time is required" id="Order_PickUpDateTime" name="Order.PickUpDateTime" style="width:200px;" type="text" value="30/04/12 16:38 PM" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Order_PickUpDateTime").datetimepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            highlightWeek: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showAnim: "scale",
            ampm: true,
            hour: 12,
            minute: 0,
            stepMinute: 5,
            hourMin: 6,
            hourMax: 16,
            showOptions: {
                origin: ["top", "left"]
            }
        });
}); 
</script>

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Order.PickUpDateTime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you see any syntax error for js when you load the page in browser?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid No, no errors.

Comment: The relevant parts from the generated HTML would help

Comment: The only thing that looks potentially problematic is having two `ready` events, but I'm not enough of a jQuery ninja to know that for certain.

Comment: @jgauffin Posted the rendered HTML for the date/time field.  Is there any other parts of the HTML that will help?

Comment: @TiesonT.: Two readys are not a problem

Comment: @jgauffin Thought so - good to know from someone with a deeper knowledgebase. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question, is the the handleUpdate function being used? It looks like it is quite similar to the onSuccess callback. Also, does it work if you move the javascript to an external file and reference it in your view?

Comment: @bhiku Yes, you are correct.  The handleUpdate was not being used.  I also tried moving the rest of the javascript to an external file but that did not affect the result.

Comment: @jgauffin  Thanks for clearing up the 'two readys' question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

I removed the following jQuery reference from the top of my page and my date/time picker started working again:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This file was already being referenced in my Razor Shared/_Layout.cshtml 'master page'.

I don't know why this double reference was causing the datetime picker to not work, but I'd love to hear anybodys thoughts on it.